# How to get data from requests-cache

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I have

`CachedSession(backend='memory', expire_after=timedelta(days=1))`

in my code. It works fine. But I want to use data from my cache, which contain in my memory. I looked for in doc, but unfortunately get nothing. Anybody know how to get cache-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods of the [`CachedSession` object(`cache_session.cache.url`)](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/inspection.html#cache-contents) to loop through all the urls which are currently cached.

> You can use CachedSession.cache.urls to see all URLs currently in the cache:

```
session = CachedSession()
print(session.cache.urls)
>>> ['https://httpbin.org/get', 'https://httpbin.org/stream/100']
```

> If needed, you can get more details on cached responses via CachedSession.cache.responses, which is a dict-like interface to the cache backend. See CachedResponse for a full list of attributes available.

> For example, if you wanted to to see all URLs requested with a specific method:

```
post_urls = [
    response.url for response in session.cache.responses.values()
    if response.request.method == 'POST'
]
```

> You can also inspect CachedSession.cache.redirects, which maps redirect URLs to keys of the responses they redirect to.

> Additional keys() and values() wrapper methods are available on BaseCache to get combined keys and responses.

```
print('All responses:')
for response in session.cache.values():
    print(response)

print('All cache keys for redirects and responses combined:')
print(list(session.cache.keys()))
```